# FieldValue.increment does not work but adds "operand"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using a firebase database and a simple function with the new [FieldValue.increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment) to increment a counter but that does not work but adds "operand" field without ever incrementing it.

My function is super simple:

```
exports.updateCounters = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // grab the parameters.
  const username = req.query.username;

  var updateObject = { };
  updateObject[username] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
  admin.database().ref('counterstest').update(updateObject);
});
```

When I deploy and call this function I would expect to see

```
countertest: {
  myusername: 1
}
```

but I see

```
countertest: {
  myusername: {
    operand: 1
  }
}
```

instead and operand: 1 never increments even if I call my function multiple times.

Can somebody point out what error I'm making here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FieldValue.increment()` is a feature of Cloud Firestore, but you're apparently trying to apply it to Realtime Database.  This is not going to work - they are different databases, and Realtime Database doesn't support atomic increments like this.

What you're actually doing here is writing the JSON representation of the returned FieldValue object to Realime Database.  Apparently, internally, the FieldValue object has a property called "operand" which contains the value to increment by.

Comment: oh, well that explains a lot. Thank Doug, I have not realized that this is tied to the Firestore only

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a couple of years old, but `database.ServerValue.increment` works with the 11.X `firebase-admin` Realtime Database like so:

```
admin.database().ref('counterstest').update({ myusername: database.ServerValue.increment(1)  })
```