# Unable to use FieldValue.increment method

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am trying to increment number field using react-native-firebase's increment method, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> No static method increment(D)Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue;in class Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue;or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue' appears in /data/app/com....

I have searched extensively for the above issue, but couldn't find a solution. Also checked that there is a static method 'increment' in FieldValue module in /node_modules/react-native-firebase/dist/modules/firestore/FieldValue.js.

Following is the code snippet:

```
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

const updateNumber = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

await db.collection('collection').doc(key).update({
  subscribednumber: updateNumber
});
```

Versions used:

"firebase": "^6.6.1",

"react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",

Comment: Are you using Firebase or Cloud Firestore? Do not forget that they are two different databases, and Firebase Realtime Database does not support atomic increments like `FieldValue.increment()`. If you are using Cloud Firestore, this [guide](https://invertase.io/blog/getting-started-with-cloud-firestore-on-react-native) may come in handy. Notice that they are using `import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';`, as the example shows. Check this other [SO case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589610/fieldvalue-increment-does-not-work-but-adds-operand)

Comment: I am using cloud firestore. Please check the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5"
```

in build.gradle.

Whereas, this functionality has been added in 18.2. So, I had to update my dependency and it worked.

Thanks!